# How can I systematically work out compiler errors?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

I am trying to learn C++ more in depth, and so I've been toying around with various aspects of the language to help solidify my understanding of what is valid syntax and what isn't.  Because the code I'm using to learn more about these specific concepts in the language is small and specifically tailored to test out one or two things of interest, I'm typically able to work out compiler errors.  And yet, sometimes, even when I know the exact concept at hand that is causing the compiler error, I know that I would never be able to figure it out on my own if the same error came up in a large project.

Here's a good example:

```
const std::unordered_map<std::string,int> mymap = { {"hello", 1} };

int main()
{
    int num = mymap["hello"];  // error
}
```

> const-unordered-map.cpp:10:28: error: passing ‘const std::unordered_mapstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
> 10 |     int num = mymap["hello"];

aka:  Passing a const unordered_map as 'this' argument discards qualifiers

I understand the bracket operator is not valid for a const map, and that a qualifier refers to a cv-qualifier ('const' in this case) and despite that, I still don't really understand how I could systematically approach an error like this one and find a resolution (other than googling)

I want to learn how to get good at working these issues out for myself though.  I've searched online for tips in this regard.  Typically answers suggest:

1. Knowing how the build process actually works will help - I am already currently working on this and I think I have a decent overall understanding.  Perhaps my inability to understand this error is just indicative of my having a further way to go in this regard
2. Simply learning over time by being diligent - I intend to do this, I will begin keeping notes on interesting compiler errors and how to understand them

So I'd like to know how you'd go about resolving this error, and if you have any further suggestions for learning the structure/style/jargon of compiler errors in general.

Part 2 of this question is: are some types of errors standardized in any way?  I'd imagine that a parser in any C++ compiler would trigger the same compiler errors, but how similar can I expect them to be?

Comment: Generally you start at the top and work your way down. Often an early mistake confuses the compiler enough to spawn subsequent error diagnostics.

Comment: Apologies for clearing all of the close votes. I stupidly closed as a duplicate before remembering the question wasn't strictly about this one error.

Comment: As for your second question, I would not expect much uniformity at all. gcc and clang may be similar (I don't know that for a fact either way), but I would expect MSVC to be quite different in the language used to describe errors.

Comment: There is no "systematic", cookie-cutter, paint-by-numbers, approach for taking an arbitrary C++ compiler error and figuring out exactly what the problem is, and how to fix it. C++ is just too complicated. You will gain the required knowledge only by gaining it with time, and experience. After a certain point you will start dimly recognizing what a compiler is trying to do, why it fails, and where the clue is. And, no, there are no "standardized" error messages, of any kind. Welcome to C++!

Comment: No small amount of understanding and resolving error messages comes down to practice. One of the tricks I use is to throw the code at multiple compilers when an error message confuses me. If GCC's diagnostic is arcane, perhaps clang or Visual Studio will emit a messages that fit better in my head. Matt Godbolt's [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nMxfe9e7K) is a beautiful tool for this.

Comment: And really the way you learn this is by learning the language and learning what sort of diagnostic your compiler emits in different situations. Basically, you should be used to the language enough that the message should give you a fairly good idea what the problem is, even if in more complicated code it is difficult to pin down exactly where it is in the given line.

Comment: "Generally you start at the top and work your way down. Often an early mistake confuses the compiler enough to spawn subsequent error diagnostics" -- this.  One missing ";" or bracket will trigger 100+ later fake errors in a larger file.  Visual C++ even has (or had) a fixed maximum on how many errors it would emit per file because of this.  One tricky thing is an error in an .h file can be hard to spot because it triggers errors in .cpp files.   It can help to stop and check in, zip up, or just copy your source folder every so often so you can see what changed recently.

Comment: One thing you will learn very quickly is not to try to fix them all. Fix the first few and recompile.